# Delphi - How can I change a single item Backgroundcolor in a TControlList

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

I try to get that white/grey pattern with the TControlList but was not able to find the right Property. ItemColor changes the backgroundcolor of every Item and Color itself changes Background for the complet control.

I had tried to manipulate the aCanvas object inside the OnBeforeDrawItem Event but that doesn't work either. Inside the documentation is loud silence.

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use canvas only set itemcolor

```
procedure TForm1.ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
if Odd(aIndex)
  then ControlList1.ItemColor:=clWhite
  else ControlList1.ItemColor:=clLtGray;
end;
```

[image: alternate rows for TControlList]

Comment: There was a Indexfailure and my testing was weak. Thank you for pointing that out.